# React GET request adds character to the end

Tags: html, reactjs, server, get, proxy-server

I am trying to create a proxy server, which will use the deployed service on Amazon EC2 to render photos. Whenever I connect to the server and load the page, this is the error message that I get :

GET http://127.0.0.1:55055/restaurant/65/%3C 404 (Not Found)

GET http://127.0.0.1:55055/restaurant/65/! 404 (Not Found)

GET http://127.0.0.1:55055/restaurant/65/D 404 (Not Found)

GET http://127.0.0.1:55055/restaurant/65/O 404 (Not Found)

GET http://127.0.0.1:55055/restaurant/65/C 404 (Not Found)

In my code, the get request is `http://ec2-34-201-243-233.compute-1.amazonaws.com/restaurant/${restaurantId}`

Why are random characters (%3C, !, D, etc.) added to the end of the url and how can I prevent this from happening?

Here is my HTML:

```
<body>
    <div id="Photos"></div>
    <script src="https://s3-us-west-1.amazonaws.com/my-bucket-name/bundle.js"></script>
    <script>

        ReactDOM.render(
            React.createElement(Photos),
            document.getElementById('Photos')
        );

    </script>
</body>
```

Comment: The code that's actually _making_ the request would be tremendously more helpful here

Comment: As @kingdaro said, can you put up the code for the `Photos` element? Looking at you have so far, it looks like the `C`, `D`, etc., is the `restaurantId` you're passing in, but why that comes up with 404s we can't tell without more code.